# Error while using pathdependent types from extended class

Tags: scala, types

I've stumbled upon non-descriptive error and could not find, what do the scala compiler require from me.

```
class Store {
  case class Box[T](box : T)
  def box[T](b : T) = Box[T](b)
  def unbox[T](b : Box[T]) : T = b.box
}

class Parent(val s : Store) {
  val box : s.Box[Int] = s.box[Int](2)
}

class Child(s : Store) extends Parent(s) {
  val unbox : Int = s.unbox[Int](box)
}
```

I got following error:

```
DependentPassing.scala:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Child.this.s.Box[Int]
 required: Child.this.s.Box[Int]

  val unbox : Int = s.unbox[Int](box)
```

How can identical types be mismatched?

*Note:* store could not be modified, it goes as is (see scala.reflect.macros.Context). So only the latter code may be adjusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the name of the var in Child ctor, leaving `s.unbox`:

```
class Child(d : Store) extends Parent(d) {
  val unbox : Int = s.unbox[Int](box)
}
```

It will work.

The reason why you had that is because scala considered `Child.s` and `Parent.s` different types, so you have all path-dependent types differ as well

Answer (score 2):

If we make the following changes it works.

```
class Store {
  case class Box[T](box : T)
  def box[T](b : T) = Box[T](b)
  def unbox[T](b : Store#Box[T]) : T = b.box
}

class Parent(val s : Store) {
  val box : Store#Box[Int] = s.box[Int](2)
}
```

So in the initial formulation it seems that we haven't convinced the compiler that in general the parent and child share the same store. In the initial formulation  the parent's box method specifies it returns a box belonging to it's store, and the unbox method takes a box belong to its store.  The changes above relax this to any old box.

Comment: Store.Box is already defined with dependent type restrictions, I may not loose them

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the Store class as corn_dog suggest, then you can try change the Parent class:

```
class Store {
  case class Box[T](box : T)
  def box[T](b : T) = Box[T](b)
  def unbox[T](b : Box[T]) : T = b.box
}
trait Box {
  val s: Store
  def box: s.Box[Int] = s.box[Int](2)
}

trait UnBox extends Box {
  def unbox : Int = s.unbox[Int](box)
}

class Parent(val s : Store) extends Box {
}

class Child(s : Store) extends Parent(s) with UnBox {
}
```

I dont know why it fail with classes, but with traits it seems to work fine.
For splitting functionality using trait is better anyway, since it allow more compositions.

Comment: I want to split functionality between two classes, that was the reason behind two separate classes. In your case I should concentrate all work in the single class, other class is not used